# How to auto populate a textbox in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple from that a user will complete to submit a "newswire". When the form loads on the create view I want the author Input to auto populate with the logged in username inside the text box in the view. Can anyone comment on what I'm doing wrong?

my model:

```
public class NewsWire
 {

      public int ID { get; set; }
      public int VendorID { get; set; }
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }          
      public string Subject { get; set; }
      public string NewsItem { get; set; }
      //public string Author { get; set; }

      public string Author
      {
           get
           {
               return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
           }
      }
  }
```

In the form for the author section I have this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>
```

I have tried several variations but still not getting it right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model:

```
public class NewsWire
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int VendorID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }          
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string NewsItem { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

and inside the controller action that renders this view populate the `Author` property from the currently logged in user:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new NewsWire
    {
        Author = User.Identity.Name
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: ah...I was thinking it through the wrong way! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, something I've noticed is that you're creating an Editor, but the Author only has a { get; } in the model. That could be a problem!

You should keep it as a property, but populate Author when you initialise the object.